# comment_email hook doesn't seem to work for comment editor field

Tags: plugin-development, comments, hooks

I am building a plugin that allows users to PPK encrypt their users' IP/email data. Thus, IP/email data is set to dummy values in the comments table and encrypted values are stored in corresponding meta fields. I'm successfully using the `comment_email` hook to lookup email addresses in the admin comments browser from my encrypted meta values.

When editing a comment in the admin interface, in the **Author** box the email field is preceded by the label "E-mail (send e-mail)", where the text in brackets is hyperlinked to the email address. My hook appears to operate correctly there, retrieving the encrypted email address from comment metadata and decrypting it before returning it.

However in the edit field itself, the real (dummy) contents of `wp_comments.comment_author_email` is revealed. Is there a hook I can use to modify this before the screen opens? I thought perhaps `preprocess_comment` would do it, but it doesn't seem to be called.

(I *can* solve this by adding an AJAX op to this screen and modifying the edit box contents after the screen is rendered. However, that's a bit hacky, and may be impossible if I try to apply it to the Quick Edit AJAX feature).

Comment: You want to display the decrypted email address in the text field?

Comment: @RutwickGangurde - yes indeed. My plan would then be to re-encrypt it, save that to meta data, and overwrite the value in the comment table with a dummy value again.

Comment: Glad you found a solution below! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to filter `'get_comment'`. The filter is part of the function with the same name. It is called in `wp-admin/comment.php?action=editcomment` and the comment is passed to the edit form where you see the email.

The parameter is a `comment` object, you can change the email value here.

Comment: Aha, too easy! I will give that a try, thanks. Oddly, I can't find that [in the filter reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) - should that be in there?

Comment: @halfer Always read the core source code, do not rely on third party documentation. Hooks are moving targets, and very few people keep the codex up to date. I found that by looking at `wp-admin/comment.php` and `wp-includes/comment.php`.

Comment: Heh, Wordpress is a third party? `:-p`. Fair point though, I will bear that in mind.